# How do I add a <br> into my ERB tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got a button that looks like this:
[image: button as it looks in the browser]

Code for the button is :

```html
<%=  mail_to "example@email.com", 'Request more info about holiday extensions here', Subject: "Hi Please include your name and email address", class: 'button-email' %>
```

How can I add a br tag so that the button text is displayed on 2 rows starting from "**about**"

**REQUEST MORE INFO ABOUT**

**HOLIDAY EXTENSIONS HERE**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Ruby on Rails** you can do like this:

```
<%=  mail_to "example@email.com", "Request more info about <br />holiday extensions here".html_safe, Subject: "Hi Please include your name and email address", class: 'button-email' %>
```

Answer (score 4):

mail_to can take a block so do:

```
<%=  mail_to "example@email.com", subject: "Hi Please include your name", class: 'button-email' do
  <span>Request more info about</span> <br> <span>holiday extensions here</span>
 end %>
```

You don't need the span tags but if you want to style them with color/embolden you can.